# How to save photo location as a string variables of a class?

Tags: c#, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8, winrt-xaml

In my application, the user uses the PhotoChooserTask to select a photo from the Camera Roll. I would like to save the **location** of the photo into a string variable of the LogEntry class so I'll be able to reload the photo at a later time as needed.

Log is an ObservableCollection of LogEntry class of items.

```
public ObservableCollection<LogEntry> Log = new ObservableCollection<LogEntry>();
```

How can I do that without saving the Photo into a Byte array in LogEntry and without saving the Photo into the IsolatedStorage?

Comment: You just need to add the photo location into the list. Why do you bother with saving the photo into bytes and IsolatedStorage?

Comment: The question is how one find the photo location in the way Windows Phone expect it and will understand it. No, I do not want to save as bytes or IsolatedStorage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First I save the name of the Picture selected and the name of the Album in a property in my each of the LogEntry items.

To load the picture from the Picture Albums:

```
        public BitmapImage GetPicture( string FileName )
        {
        // Work around for known bug in the media framework.  Hits the static constructors
        // so the user does not need to go to the picture hub first.
        MediaPlayer.Queue.ToString();

        MediaLibrary ml = null;
        PictureAlbum cameraRoll = null;
        PictureAlbum savedPictures = null;
        PictureAlbum samplePictures = null;
        PictureAlbum favoritePictures = null;

        int index = FileName.IndexOf( "\\" );
        string albumName = FileName.Remove( index, FileName.Length - index );
        string fileName = FileName.Remove( 0, index + 1 );

        foreach ( MediaSource source in MediaSource.GetAvailableMediaSources() )
            {
            if ( source.MediaSourceType == MediaSourceType.LocalDevice )
                {
                ml = new MediaLibrary( source );
                PictureAlbumCollection allAlbums = ml.RootPictureAlbum.Albums;

                foreach ( PictureAlbum album in allAlbums )
                    {
                    if ( album.Name == "Camera Roll" )
                        {
                        cameraRoll = album;
                        }
                    else if ( album.Name == "Saved Pictures" )
                        {
                        savedPictures = album;
                        }
                    else if ( album.Name == "Sample Pictures" )
                        {
                        samplePictures = album;
                        }
                    else if ( album.Name == "Favorite Pictures" )
                        {
                        favoritePictures = album;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        PictureAlbum Album;
        switch ( albumName )
            {
            case "Camera Roll":
                Album = cameraRoll;
                break;

            case "Saved Pictures":
                Album = savedPictures;
                break;

            case "Sample Pictures":
                Album = samplePictures;
                break;

            case "Favorite Pictures":
                Album = favoritePictures;
                break;

            default:
                Album = null;
                break;
            }

        if ( Album == null )
            {
            return new BitmapImage();
            }

        BitmapImage b = new BitmapImage();
        foreach ( Picture p in Album.Pictures.Take( Album.Pictures.Count ) )
            {
            if ( fileName == p.Name )
                {
                b.SetSource( p.GetThumbnail() );
                break;
                }
            }

        return b;
        }
```